# BatchErrorException: The specified operation is not valid for the current state of the resource

Tags: azure, azure-batch

**Scenario**:
I have a job created in azure batch against a pool. Now, I created another pool and want to point my job to the newly created pool.
I use the azure-batch SDK to write the following piece of code

```
import azure.batch.batch_service_client as batch
batch_service_client = batch.BatchServiceClient(credentials, batch_url = account_url)

job_id="LinuxTrainingJob"
pool_id="linux-e6a63ad4-9e52-4b9a-8b09-2a0249802981"

pool_info = batch.models.PoolInformation(pool_id=pool_id)
job_patch_param = batch.models.JobPatchParameter(pool_info=pool_info)
batch_service_client.job.patch(job_id, job_patch_param)
```

This gives me the following error

```
BatchErrorException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-ada32b24d6a0> in <module>
      2 pool_info = batch.models.PoolInformation(pool_id=pool_id)
      3 job_patch_param = batch.models.JobPatchParameter(pool_info=pool_info)
----> 4 batch_service_client.job.patch(job_id, job_patch_param)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/batch/operations/job_operations.py in patch(self, job_id, job_patch_parameter, job_patch_options, custom_headers, raw, **operation_config)
    452 
    453         if response.status_code not in [200]:
--> 454             raise models.BatchErrorException(self._deserialize, response)
    455 
    456         if raw:

BatchErrorException: {'additional_properties': {}, 'lang': 'en-US', 'value': 'The specified operation is not valid for the current state of the resource.\nRequestId:46074112-9a99-4569-a078-30a7f4ad2b91\nTime:2020-10-06T17:52:43.6924378Z'}
```

The credentials are set above and are working properly as I was able to create pool and jobs using the same client.

Environment details

```
azure-batch==9.0.0
python 3.8.3
Ubuntu 18.04
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assign a Job to another Pool you must call the [disableJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/job/disable) API to drain currently running tasks from the Pool. Then you can call [updateJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/job/update) to assign a new poolId to run on. Once it is updated you can then call [enableJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/job/enable) to continue the jobs execution.